# Value get is not a member of java.io.Serializable

Tags: scala

I have written 2 codes .The functionality of both the code is same.Both the codes take user data then store it in map and on providing keys we get correspoding user data. I have written an extra logic in code2, whic I have mentioned below.

Code1:

```
class user(var name:String,var id:Int, var gender:Option[String])
{
override def toString="("+ name+","+id+","+gender+")"
}
object a
{
def main(args:Array[String]):Unit={
var a=new user("kl",90,Some("Male"))
println(a.name,a.id,a.gender)//ACESS VALUES

 //DEFINING MAP
 var mm=Map(1-> new user("jh",189,Some("Male")),2->new user("gh",12,None),3
  ->new user("io",100,Some("Female")))

  // defining method giving o/p value of specific key of mm

 def getkey(i:Int)=
 { mm.get(i)
 }
 var u1=getkey(readLine("ENTER THE KEY").toInt) // some[user]
 println(u1.getClass.getName)
 if(u1.isDefined)
 {
 println(u1.get+","+u1.get.name+","+u1.get.id+","+u1.get.gender)
 }
 }
 }
```

Code1 1 works properly and O/P is right. I have added extra logic in Code2. The extra logic is getKey method. I have written a code for checking whether the input key is present in map. There I am getting an error:

```
 **value get is not a member of java.io.Serializable**_
```

Code2:

```
class user(var name:String,var id:Int, var gender:Option[String]) 
{
override def toString="("+ name+","+id+","+gender+")"
}
object a
{
def main(args:Array[String]):Unit={
var a=new user("kl",90,Some("Male"))
println(a.name,a.id,a.gender)//ACESS VALUES

//DEFINING MAP
var mm=Map(1-> new user("jh",189,Some("Male")),2->new user("gh",12,None),3-> new user("io",100,Some("Female")))

 // defining method giving o/p value of specific key of mm
 def getkey(i:Int)=
 {  
 //EXTRA LOGIC
 var a=(mm.keys).toList
 if(a.contains(i)){mm.get(i)}
 else {"NO SUCH ELEMENT EXCEPTION , KEY DOESNT MATCH"}
 }

 print("ENTER THE KEY \n")

 var u1=getkey(1) // some[user]
 println(u1.get)

 }
 }
```

ERROR -

```
enter code here
eg1.Option.scala:27: error: value get is not a member of 
java.io.Serializable
println(u1.get)
       ^
one error found
```

Why does the seriliazable errors occurs in Code2 and not in Code1? Is the error due extra logic in Code2? How to fix an error?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It happens because your getKey function return type is `io.Serializable`.
Reason for this is that every branch of your `if` expression is returning a different type:

```
def getkey(i:Int) = { // io.Serializable
  //EXTRA LOGIC
  var a=(mm.keys).toList
  if(a.contains(i)) { mm.get(i) } // option here
  else { "NO SUCH ELEMENT EXCEPTION , KEY DOESNT MATCH" } // string here
}
```

Consider rewriting your function, so its return type is `Option[User]`, one way of doing so is:

```
def getkey(i:Int): Option[user] = { 
  //EXTRA LOGIC
  var a=(mm.keys).toList
  if(a.contains(i)) { mm.get(i) }
  else { None }
}
```

However, there is no need for checking keys, you can simplify this function to:

```
def getkey(i:Int): Option[user] = { 
  //EXTRA LOGIC
  m.get(i)
}
```

*Hint: write expected return type for functions to see what's going wrong in such cases.*

Comment: I was about to comment doing the same recommendation: while type declaration is optional in many cases in Scala, making it explicit has some advantages. Besides helping finding bugs early, it may also speed up compilation times.

Comment: @pedrorijo91, agreed. Also, it's nice to prototype with the explicit return type. Just quick `def mySum(a: Type, b: Type): Type = ???` and I already can call this function and be sure about types without worrying about implementation at the moment.